# Angular Electron not working on first load

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I have tried building an Angular application with Electron and I have the following issue: When the app starts, the browser window is empty, nothing in the console. The whole body tag is empty as well. However, after I manually press reload in the Electron browser, it works - everything runs as expected. Any ideas why this might happen?

This is my main.js file:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const {autoUpdater} = require("electron-updater");
const log = require('electron-log');

const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");
var webpackTargetElectronRenderer = require('webpack-target-electron-renderer');


autoUpdater.logger = log;
autoUpdater.logger.transports.file.level = 'info';
log.info('App starting...');

let win;

function sendStatusToWindow(text) {
  log.info(text);
  console.log(text);
  mainWindow.console.log(text);
  win.webContents.send('message', text);
}
// function createDefaultWindow() {
//   win = new BrowserWindow();
//   win.webContents.openDevTools();
//   win.on('closed', () => {
//     win = null;
//   });
//   win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/version.html#v${app.getVersion()}`);
//   return win;
// }

app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  // On certificate error we disable default behaviour (stop loading the page)
  // and we then say "it is all fine - true" to the callback
  console.log(JSON.stringify(certificate));
  event.preventDefault();
  callback(true);
});

let mainWindow


var options = {
  // webPreferences: {
  //   webSecurity: false
  // },
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  }
}

options.target = webpackTargetElectronRenderer(options)

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
    // webPreferences: {
      // plugins: true,
      // nodeIntegration: true,
      // webSecurity: false
    // }
  })

  // log.info('Hello, log');
  // log.info(log.transports.console);
  // console.log(log.transports.console);
  // log.warn('Some problem appears');
  // // log.info("Test");
  // console.log = log.info;
  console.log("TEst");
  // log.info(log.transports.file.getFile());
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
      protocol: "file:", 
      slashes: true
    })
  );
  // mainWindow.webContents.devToolsWebContents("Test");
  // var x = path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`);
  // console.log(x);
  // mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/version.html#v${app.getVersion()}`);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  // console.log("Test");

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
    sendStatusToWindow('Checking for update...');
  })
  autoUpdater.on('update-available', (ev, info) => {
    sendStatusToWindow('Update available.');
  })
  autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (ev, info) => {
    sendStatusToWindow('Update not available.');
  })
  autoUpdater.on('error', (ev, err) => {
    sendStatusToWindow('Error in auto-updater.');
  })
  autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (ev, progressObj) => {
    sendStatusToWindow('Download progress...');
  })
  autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (ev, info) => {
    sendStatusToWindow('Update downloaded; will install in 5 seconds');
  });

}

// app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('ready', function()  {
  createWindow();
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary answer: manually reloaded the window after it loaded. I will try to come up with something better.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).